# Runtime patching of ELF binary

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I have a shared object of a program that I need to have a instruction changed from a 'jne/je' to a jmp. I've attempted to look around for example on how to do this maybe with LD_PRELOAD or something to no avail.

Comment: How about patching the shared object binary on disk?

Comment: That seems feasible, but my software updates automatically once a day, rendering this unfeasible.

Comment: What about binary patching though? I looked into that, but what if my offsets change due to a change in the size of my shared object due to a vendor update?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like the kind of thing I used to apply to Amiga/Atari ST executables to bypass copy protection ;-)

Comment: This isn't any kind of copyright stuff. My programs internal clock counter is limited to a fixed number which gives reduced performance, so changing the jne/je to a jmp removes the limit and it works better.

Answer (score 5):

Whether this is technically possible depends on a few things:

1. `jne` / `je` instructions come in different lengths:

   - one-byte opcode (`0x74` / `0x75`) plus signed 8-bit offset (i.e. two bytes in total)
   - two-byte opcode (`0xf0` plus `0x84` / `0x85`,) plus signed 32-bit offset (i.e. six bytes in total)

   the same for the `jmp` instruction (in 64bit mode, a total of five different encodings between two and nine bytes, depending on whether the `jmp` is relative / absolute).
   This means you can only replace a `jne`/`je` with `jmp` if the target of your `jmp` is "close enough" to choose a size-compatible opcode. For a 32bit-relative `jne`/`je` you can usually substitute, but for a near (8-bit) one that's usually not possible as there won't be "free instruction space" within +/- 128  Bytes.
2. if you have a "compatible opportunity" wrt. to the size of the instruction, you've got the two tasks to address that you've mentioned yourself already:

   - intercepting the shared object load so you can substitute before the library is used.
   - finding the address of the function you wish to patch (assuming it changes).

   How this could be done depends on your operating system; on UN*X-like, you could try using `LD_PRELOAD` to load a custom library *of your own* that does nothing than `dlopen()` the library you wish to modify, then `dlsym()` to find the routine, then substitute the code, but never call `dlclose()` to make sure the modified copy is kept around (i.e. not unloaded) instead of the original when later (via dynamic linking) the lib is accessed again.

The system administrator usually has ways to mitigate (or even disable) `LD_PRELOAD` (and for setuid-executables that run as root, it's always ignored), because it's got obvious implications on system integrity / security. So whether that technique can be used or not depends on the specific setup you have.

If all the above conditions are met, then something like:

```
int patch_je_jne(void *instr, void *tgt_address)
{
    char *je_jne = (char*)instr;
    char *iaddr = je_jne;

    switch (je_jne[0]) {
    case JE_8BIT_OP:
    case JNE_8BIT_OP:
        iaddr += 2;
        tgt_address -= iaddr;        /* adjust pc-relative */
        if ((char*)tgt_address > (char*)0xFF)
            return CANNOT_PATCH_LARGE_OFFSETS;
        je_jne[1] = (char)tgt_address;
        je_jne[0] = JMP_OP;
        return PATCH_SUCCESS;

    case 0xF0:                       /* marker for a 32bit-relative JE/JNE */
        if (je_jne[1] != JE_32BIT_OP && je_jne[1] != JNE_32BIT_OP))
            break;
        iaddr += 6;
        tgt_address -= iaddr;        /* adjust pc-relative */
        *((char**)(je_jne + 2)) = tgt_address;
        je_jne[1] = JMP_32BIT_OP;
        return PATCH_SUCCESS;
    }
    return CANNOT_PATCH_THIS_INSTR;
}
```

might do it. As said, no verification / validation in this code beyond checking that the instruction opcodes at the to-be-patched address are compatible.

The main work, as mentioned, is in *safely determining* where / how you need to apply the hook.

As it's been suggested, a comment on patching the binary library instead of the running (loaded) library: The key question there is: What's the target of the `jmp`, can you *know it in advance* ?
In binary patching, you need to determine that at the time when you modify the binary, which, together with operating system behaviour such as ASLR (address space layout randomization) is difficult to impossible - you need a pre-known, unchanging target address in your executable, but usually you only have a *relative* `jmp` available, i.e. do not know in advance which code location that'll end up with due to ASLR. It all depends *where* you want the `jmp` to go to.

Comment: There is possibly an extra hoop to jump through: the text section of the library loaded at runtime is possibly mapped as read/execute only, writes denied.

Comment: That's true but also only a `mprotect()` away. The dynamic linker, at load/link time, _requires_ modifying parts of the loaded code (those that contain relocation references), i.e. the procedure as such happens as part of normal functionality.

Comment: What's the best way to get the address of it in memory? I want to see if Frank's method will work correctly. The jne/je in the function appears to jump to another function and nothing else.

Comment: As indicated, _that_ is the difficult part. The function's start address you can lookup via `dlsym()` but finding the offset of a specific instruction within (or even, just the _presence_ of said instruction) requires disassembling the machine code for that function. Disassembly libraries exist which help with this (look, for example, through the DTrace fasttrap/PID provider sourcecode). Before you attempt such, I suggest trying the patching by hand using a debugger. When that works, a LD_PRELOAD with a hardcoded offset (valid for a specific version of the DLL). Then - ... imagination rules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just Hex edit your object ? Get the right offset and opcode with objdump, and edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers on how to find the instruction in updated binaries more or less automatically.

If you know where the instruction is in one version of the binary, you may disassemble a chunk of code around it (maybe include some code that transfers control to there or is transferred control from there?), and save that disassembly. Drop instruction addresses from the disassembly and from its jmp/call instructions' immediate operands as those are likely to change from version to version anyway.

Disassemble the newer version similarly, find the place that matches best to what you have disassembled previously and patch it. For matching you might use some diff tool.

This, of course, will only work if that code around the instruction of interest doesn't change and is unique.

Some checksum updating might be needed too in the binary. OTOH, if you're an admin, you can probably patch it in the memory.